# Is salesforce apex rest parameter name case sensitive?

Tags: apexrest, sfrestrequest

Let's consider the following rest request url for example
https://login.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/paramcheck?User_ID=013456

Is parameter 'User_ID' case-sensitive? 
Can I use 'user_id' instead of 'User_ID'?

Provided there is a apex rest webservice class to process the rest request parameters.

Salesforce reference document link for this would be very helpful

Comment: Yes Logesh..it is case sensitive...i personally prefer using all small characters...

Comment: Thanks Santosh :) Do you know any salesforce documentation link for this? That would be really helpful!

Comment: Here is the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm):

> The URL mapping is case-sensitive. A URL mapping for my_url will only match a REST resource containing my_url and not My_Url.

It is not clear in documentation if parameter names are also case-sensitive but these are. In a REST class you use RestContext.request.params which returns you a Map. And Map keys in Apex are case-sensitive so your parameter names are case-sensitive.

If you are creating REST services that are consumed by other developer it can be a difficult for them to realise this and supply proper case-sensitive parameters. This problem can be further amplified if developer are off-platform i.e using .Net/Java/Ruby and don't have any knowledge about apex.

To solve this we can let developer choose whatever way they prefer to send parameter and implement a way in our REST service code to gracefully handle this.

Just convert all map keys to lower case and store in another map and use that map in rest of your code. Here is a code snippet to explain this.

```
//Map to store request parameter and values after converting parameter name(map key) in lower case. parameter names in get request can come in mixed case but Map keys are case sensitive
//Hence to get a correct value convert all map keys to lower case and then look in map using lower case key values
Map<String, String> requestParams = new Map<String, String>();
for(String param: RestContext.request.params.keySet())
    requestParams.put(param.toLowerCase(), RestContext.request.params.get(param));
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for detailed explanation! Appreciate your help!